# Find the cost of all paths in a matrix using Dijkstra's Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, dijkstra, path-finding

I'm trying to create a program that from a starting coordinate finds the lowest cost path of traveling to all of the other coordinates in a matrix using Dijkstra's Algorithm. Any coordinate that has an infinite value is avoided when traversing.

Comment: It is not clear what's wrong with this code. Can you edit your question to post the wrong answer and the expected one ?

Comment: I've edited my question now

Comment: is there a specific reason you are using Dijkstra as an algorithm like goal based pathfinding would make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `node` and `current_node`:

```
        x_check = node[0] + move[0]
        y_check = node[1] + move[1]
```

should be

```
        x_check = current_node[0] + move[0]
        y_check = current_node[1] + move[1]
```

By the way, in Python, you are allowed to write

```
        if 0 <= x_check <= N-1 and 0 <= y_check <= N-1:
```

which is much more readable !